# If a linear group $G$ has an Abelian dense subgroup $H$, then $G$ itself is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, abelian-groups

I am having a lot of trouble with this proving the following statement:
If a linear group $G$ has an Abelian dense subgroup $H$, then $G$ itself is abelian. More specifically, the notion of a "dense subgroup" is confusing to me. I was trying to compare this idea to maybe something like $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but that example was too trivial to really help me with the proof I am actually trying to complete. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I wonder why the two answers use commutators. One can use the two maps $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ resp. $yx$ directly. That being said, the statement also holds for monoids.

Answer (score 6):

Linear groups are examples of [**topological groups**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group): these are groups equipped with a topology such that the group operations (multiplication and inverse) are continuous. *Density* in the context of topological groups means exactly what it means in general topology - and as a good example, $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is a dense subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$.

The idea is that since being abelian is defined via the group operations, if it holds densely it should hold always. This can be formalized by finding a *continuous function* corresponding to "abelian-ness": namely, take $f(a, b)=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ (the [**commutator map**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator)). Then $f(a, b)=e$ iff $ab=ba$.

So what? Well, $f$ is continuous since the group operations are continuous (exercise), and by hypothesis is equal to $e$ on a dense set. But if a continuous function is constant on a dense set, then it's just constant - this is a general fact of topology. So $f(a, b)=e$ always, which is to say the group is abelian.

*This second-to-last sentence uses the further assumption that $\{e\}$ is closed; this is not necessarily true, but is true in every "naturally-occurring" topological group. In particular, every linear group has this property, as does every metrizable group more generally.*

Note that the only special thing we've used about abelian-ness is that it's given by an *equation*: namely, $G$ is commutative iff $ab=ba$ for each $a, b\in G$. We can rewrite such an equation to get an expression which is always $e$ iff $G$ is abelian, namely $ab=ba\implies aba^{-1}b^{-1}=e$, and we get the function $f$ from this second equation. This same process more generally shows:

> If an equation in the language of groups is satisfied on a dense set, then it's satisfied everywhere.

For instance, if $a^2b^4a^6b^8=e$ for all $a, b\in D$ for some dense $D\subseteq G$, then $a^2b^4a^6b^8=e$ for all $a, b\in G$.

This *fails* for properties more complicated than equations - e.g. consider the group $G=(\{q+z\pi: q\in\mathbb{Q}, z\in\mathbb{Z}\}, +)$. $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is a dense subset of $G$, and every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is *even* - that is, for each $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, there is some $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a+a=b$ - but $\pi$ is not even in $G$ (since ${\pi\over 2}$ isn't in $G$). The point is that "is even" is a more complicated statement than just "commutes" - it involves a "there exists" phrase, and it turns out that quantifiers are important here.

Comment: The neutral element should be denoted $1$ since you write the group multiplicatively. "But if a continuous function is constant on a dense set, then it's just constant" -- This uses that $\{1\}$ is closed (so it does not hold  for all spaces).

Comment: Awesome answer, as always.

Comment: @HeinrichD You're right, I missed the further condition - fixed. As to $e$ vs. $1$, I learned with $e$ being used as the identity, and I'll leave it as such.

Comment: You have still some $=0$ there.

Comment: @HeinrichD OUCH, totally missed that. Thanks!

Comment: what if $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is not continuous?

Comment: @Jakobian The inverse map has to be continuous in a topological group; if it's not, it's just a [paratopological group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paratopological_group).

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, I'm asking how we could show it in a $T_1$ paratopological group. It's one of exercises in a book so I'm trying to come up with a more general argument. I've tried lots of things but it doesn't budge

Comment: @Jakobian I'd ask that as a separate question (and btw I don't know the answer).

Comment: @NoahSchweber yeah I thought about it, I'll do it if I can't figure it out

Comment: @NoahSchweber by the way, this turned out to be false. There is an non-abelian $T_1$ paratopological group with abelian dense subgroup!

Comment: @Jakobian Huh, neat. What is it (or do you have a link to it)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah, sure, see edit to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450815/t-1-paratopological-group-having-a-dense-commutative-subgroup-is-commutative)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the groups are Lie group, the map $f:G\times G\rightarrow G$ defined by $f(x,y)=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is continue. $f(A\times A)=Id_G$, this implies that $f^{-1}(Id_A)$ is a closed subset which contains $A\times A$ so it is $G\times G$ since $A\times A$ is dense in $G\times G$. We deduce that $G$ is a commutative group.

Comment: Where do you use any Lie structure?